# Android: LinearView with fixed sized widgets left and right and a flexible one in the middle

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

Seems to be a simple question, but I can't figure out how to do it.

I have a horizontal LinearView with something of fixed size at the left, then comes some text which should take as mich space as possible, but on the right should be another fixed-size object.

Now, my problems are right now: When the text in the middle is too long, the object at the right gets pushed out of the window. When the text is too short, it does not sit at the right border of the window, but directly next to the text.

How can I do it? My Code so far (As you can see, I tried to use the LayoutWeight, which didn't help...):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/important"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#000000"
        android:layout_weight="1"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingTop="5dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="0dp"
            android:textColor="#333333"
            android:paddingBottom="0dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/description"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#666666"
            android:paddingTop="3dp"
            android:paddingRight="5dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:textSize="12sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/lastpage" 
        android:src="@drawable/lastpage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="200"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at this answer [Android: LinearView with fixed sized widgets left and right and a flexible one in the middle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4198856/android-linearview-with-fixed-sized-widgets-left-and-right-and-a-flexible-one-in) you maybe just need to set the `layout_width` of your middle element to 0px to make it not use the width gained by content but decide about it via the weight.

Hope this helps.

Comment: The link forwards back to this page

Comment: @inVINCEable Good fetch. I have no idea how this got broken or which ticket I originally quoted back then. But the solution should hopefully be understandable even without the link. Basically when using layout_weight you want to set the layout_width to 0px to allow the framework to calculate the width. In the example above the LinearLayout would need this change.

Answer (score 7):

You have `android:layout_weight="1"` on two widgets (first and second children of the `LinearLayout`), which does not match your business rules.

Personally, I would use a `RelativeLayout` here. Use `android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"` on the first child, `android:layout_alignParentRight="true"` on the third child, and `android:toLeftOf` and `android:toRightOf` on the middle, anchoring it between the outer fixed children. That more explicitly implements your desired business rules.

Comment: Dear CommonsWare, thanks for the comment, actually I tried switching to RelativeLayout, but sunadorer's solution works and I will leave it untouched now. When I can find some time, however, I will try to switch again, since this is recommended in the Android documentation. But thanks for the help!